# Pull or push through

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Are the phrases *push through* and *pull through* interchangeable? Is one more grammatically correct than the other?

Comment: A dictionary should provide the difference. Have you checked? If so, what did you find that you're still unsure about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the statement you are emphasizing on,  'push through' and 'pull through' are both phrasal verbs.

Note:  A phrasal verb is a phrase consisting of a verb and either or both of a preposition or adverb that has idiomatic meaning. Such as your examples 'pull through' and 'push through'; 'push' is a verb and 'through' could be adverb or preposition. It depends on the statement.

> The president is trying to push through various tax reforms.

Meaning: ["to cause a plan or suggestion to be officially accepted or put into use"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/push-sth-through)

> I'm glad he pulled through.

Meaning: ["To survive something"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+through)

Answer (score 2):

There is no *grammatical* difference between them, but they have different meanings.

When used literally, pushing is applying force from behind to press something through a gap; pulling is applying force from the front to draw it through.

If you're using them figuratively, it is possible that they will both do in some context: it depends on the context.

As idioms, they have specific meanings that are not interchangeable: "push something through" means to work to get it accepted or approved, or voted on. "Pull through" (intransitive) means to survive an illness or injury.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the statement you are emphasizing on,  'push through' and 'pull through are both a phrasal verb'
Note:  A phrase consisting of a verb and either or both of a preposition or adverb, that has idiomatic meaning. In your examples pull through and push through, push is a verb and through could be adverb or preposition. It depends on the statement.

> e.g: The president is trying to push through various tax reforms.

Meaning:
"To cause a plan or suggestion to be officially accepted or put into use:"

> e.g:  I'm glad he pulled through.

Meaning:

"To survive something".

You can check for more clarifications at these links:

- [pull through](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+through)
- [push through](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+through)
- [push something through](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/push-sth-through)

Answer (score 0):

***push through*** is also used colloquially as an intransitive verb meaning "to persist despite obstacles, set-backs, etc."

Ex: "I can see this and feel this importance of being present as you are describing it, and you are giving such great encouragement that you've done it, that it's not easy, and to keep **pushing through**."

From "Being Present and Being in the Moment--Video For Shy People"

Comment: The OP is asking about the difference between "push though" and "pull through". This only gives your definition of "push through", which has already been covered by other answers. Please consider adding more to your answer to fully answer the original question

Comment: I was only pointing out that there is at least one other meaning for "push through" than those already listed, so it is not necessary to fully answer the original question, as the previous post already did that. By logical extension, this additional meaning would further  support the previous answers stating that the two are not interchangeable.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, it's helpful to explicitly state all that in your answer, making reference to the answer you're adding to. Otherwise, people will read your answer and mistakenly think it constitutes an entire answer. The clue word of "also" isn't enough.